# Relay for remote access to database on shared host

Tags: database, hosted

Hosts like 1and1 and GoDaddy do not enable direct remote access to databases on their shared hosting plans.  Access is only allowed from applications running within the associated "webspace."  So, for example, one can install phpMyAdmin on the host Linux account, and then access that remotely through a browser to interface with the database.

Are there any (hopefully) convenient "relay" packages that one could install on the shared host instead that would allow conventional SQL clients to connect to the hosted databases?

I.e., we have the following situation:

```
mySQL_hosted <-XXX-> Remote SQL client
```

but

```
mySQL_hosted <-----> hosted_application <-----> Remote web client
```

So I'm looking for `hosted_application` that allows

```
mySQL_hosted <-----> hosted_application <-----> Remote SQL client
```